# Great tutorial, but can't replicate code

Tags: android, tinder

New to mobile development and thought I'd follow along with this tutorial.  This is hopefully a simple question.  If someone could just tell me what the --> is called (is it a pointer?) or what causes the (e) --> code to be light gray in color after typed, I could do some more research on my own problem here.

[youtube.com/watch?v=RagA8g9A5Qc](http://youtube.com/watch?v=RagA8g9A5Qc)

In the video link below at 10:58 (pause video) you will see some code showing

```
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener ((e) --> { {finish(); }};
```

at 10:42 in the video you see similar symbol

```
    `mProfileImage.setOnClickListener((view) --> {saveUserInformation(); }};`
```

Could someone please advise what the --> is called and how I might get the (e) --> to appear in the auto-populate functions dialog box as you start typing? Am I missing a file or class?

I think it might be an IDE settings since just above those lines of code in his video you see the following line:

```
- bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
```

but in my IDE I see the word "quality"

```
- bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality 20, baos);
```

appear when the value 20 was typed. It's a light grey color similar to the (e) and --> in his code which for some reason won't work in my editor or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `(e) -> {...}` is a lambda, you can read more about this here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html, but it's, in basic terms, a block of code that can be executed. The `e` is the parameter coming from the caller and the `->` is just syntax to denote the lambda followed by the code, the "quality" in grey letters that you mention is just the name of a parameter in the `compress` method, which the IDE shows so you can properly fill method calls without looking up the docs or the source.

EDIT: Also, bear in mind it should be `->` not `-->`, in both Java and Kotlin, that could be the source of your "grey letters" issue.

Comment: To start, sorry for the poor post syntax formatting. Been a while since I posted code questions. I went back through the tutorial videos and Video 9 @ 28:25 shows the code.  What I didn't notice is that it is just collapsed code LOL.  

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUiZhCUHXhk&list=PLxabZQCAe5fio9dm1Vd0peIY6HLfo5MCf&index=9)

He changes his public void 'onFailure()' to become the the lambda code seen shortly after.by collapsing the function on the side margin

This answered my problem. Appreciate the term for lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, the `->` operator is used for lambda functions.

A lambda is an anonymous function, useful for functions that you'll only be using once, or passing as an argument. [Read more here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).